# Лицензия GNU AGPLv3 и play market

Tags: google-play, лицензирование, юридические-аспекты

Допустим, есть опенсорсная библиотека, распространяемая под лицензией GNU AGPLv3. Я хочу использовать ее в своем приложении (исходники править не буду).

Могу ли я использовать свое приложение в коммерческих целях (выложить на маркет как free app)?
Если я нарушаю лицензию, могут ли меня вычислить и покарать?
Если я писал приложение под заказ, может ли заказчик выложить его на маркет?

Comment: Можно поступить так. Сделать приложение на базе этой библиотеки и выложить его исходники (например, на гитхаб). Но это приложение должно предоставлять доступ по http/socket/intent (то есть работать как сервис). 

А Ваше приложение, которое уже с закрытыми сорцами, использует первое приложение через его api (которое открыто и известно).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Удивительно читать упражнения отдельных деятелей даже без намека на ссылку на оригинал собственно самой лицензии. Радуют опусы типа:

> Раз либа - опенсорс, да еще и распространяется по свободной лицензии - вы ничего не нарушаете и можете свободно использовать её в своих целях.

Это распространенное заблуждение. Есть варианты, напрямую запрещающие их использование в коммерческих целях, например [Creative Common Non-Commercial](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/3.0/).

Что касается лицензии [AGPL v.3](http://licenseit.ru/wiki/index.php/GNU_Affero_General_Public_License_version_3), то условия по поводу либ довольно простые:

> При распространении не-исходных форм необходимо: 
> опубликовать на каждой копии уведомление об авторском праве, 
> сохранить все уведомления об авторских правах, 
> сохранить все уведомления об отсутствии гарантий, 
> приложить копию данной лицензии, 
> приложить заметное уведомление об изменении кода программы, 
> указать дату внесения изменений, 
> распространять на условиях данной лицензии все внесенные изменения,

В конкретном случае, указанном ТС, необходимо в пункте **About** программы сделать сноску на копирайты авторов либы, URL с локацией либы и привести текст лицензии (да-да, сделать не ссылку, а именно приложить прямо сам текст лицензии - см. *приложить копию данной лицензии*).

**Update**

Прозвучал вопрос: карают ли за нарушение лицензий? Карают-карают, так покарают, что мало не покажется. У меня удалили из маркета аппу со 100 тыс. закачек только за то, что в About не привел ссылку на лицензию на использование иконки, скачанной в WikiMedia.

**Update2**

Прозвучал еще 1 вопрос: может ли заказчик сам выложить его на маркет?

Это довольно сложный вопрос. Исходя из общей логики и здравого смысла, если вы разработали аппу под заказ, то вы лишаетесь авторских прав, и авторские права на публикацию и извлечение дохода от публикации переходят к заказчику. В реальной жизни, если у вас с заказчиком отсутствует договор об отчуждении/переходе авторских от автора к заказчику, то заказчик не имеет прав на продукт. Уже были таковые прецеденты судебных дел. Чтобы защититься, заказчику необходимо заключить письменный договор с вами, ну или на худой конец акт передачи/отчуждения авторских прав. Форма договора [обсуждалась на Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/177229/).

То есть если, не имея такого договора, заказчик опубликовал работу на маркете, то это прямое нарушение действующего законодательства, хотя с точки зрения здравого смысла он прав. Как поступить, решайте сами. И по совести, и по закону будет правильно составить бумажку, в которой говорится о переходе авторских прав от вас к заказчику.

Comment: Вы не там находите заблуждение. *Любая* свободная (англ. free, фр. libre, в англ. чаще используется эвфемизм «open source») программа / библиотека (и шире — произведение) *по определению* может быть использована в любых, в том числе коммерческих, целях. Если какая-либо лицензия авторского права ограничивает коммерческое, военное или еще какое использование, то такая лицензия *несвободна*. Отсюда CC BY-NC — это несвободная /  собственническая (англ. non-free / proprietary) лицензия.

Comment: А вопрос, о том, может ли автор / заказчик выложить программу на некий «маркет» в данном случае, как я и сказал в своем ответе, не представляет *ни малейшей* сложности. Если в программе используется бибилиотека под GNU [Affero] GPL, то это программа сама может быть только на условиях GNU [Affrero] GPL или совместимой с GNU [Affero] GPL лицензии, то есть эта программа *свободна*, а значит выложить ее на «маркет», не дискриминирующий свободные программы (Google Play к таковым не относится), за плату или бесплатно может *кто угодно*.

Answer (score 1):

Да, создавать производные работы на основе чужой работы, что на условиях GNU AGPL, и использовать результат в коммерческих целях можно. Любая свободная лицензия, [GNU Affero GPLv3](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl.html) в их числе, [по определению](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html) это разрешает¹.

Но, разумеется, необходимо соблюдать положения лицензии. А ключевое положение GNU AGPL в том, что это лицензия сильного [авторского лева](https://www.gnu.org/copyleft/) (англ. copyleft); это значит, что вы обязаны и все остальные части своего проекта, использующего библиотеку под GNU AGPL, выпустить на условиях GNU AGPL или совместимой с ней лицензии; то есть сделать ваш продукт свободным, что означает, что вы сохраняете за своими пользователями право (0) использовать ваш продукт в любых целях, (1) перераспространять его, (2) изменять его, (3) распространять измененные версии. Пункт 2 подразумевает, что вы предоставите пользователям возможность получить также полный соответствующий исходный код. На предмет подробностей стоит почитать саму лицензию и [ЧаВО](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html).

С публикацией на Google Play Market’е никаких проблем из-за лицензии возникнуть не должно². Пара примеров ПО на условиях GNU AGPL в Гуглоплэе: [BlitzMail Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.grobox.blitzmail.pro&hl=en), [ownCloud News Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.luhmer.owncloudnewsreader&hl=en). К вопросу о [коммерческом использовании](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/selling.html), можно, кстати, заметить, что оба они там доступны пусть и за скромную, но плату.

С точки зрения только авторских прав, выложить приложение туда сможете не только вы или заказчик, но и вообще любой человек, кто его получит — оно же свободное. Кому принадлежат исключительные права: вам или заказчику, здесь не очень существенно. Но есть еще рычаг давления в виде товарного знака, если кто-либо его регистрировал, — лицензии GNU *не* обязывают вас разрешать его использовать кому угодно.

Если вы нарушаете свободные лицензии, то да, разумеется, вас могут найти и покарать точно так же, как и в случае с несвободными. И хотя гражданско-процессуальные действия в защиту авторских прав, как и любых других, могут иницировать только правообладатели (или их представители) и надзорные ограны (т. е. прокуратура, которая без ущерба обычно не возбуждается); но из Гуглоплэя могут выкинуть на раз и по жалобе с третьей стороны.

---

¹ Соответственно лицензия, что ограничивает использование в коммерческих целях, например [СС-BY-NC](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/4.0/legalcode), есть несвободная.

² А вот с Apple AppStore — могут быть, ибо Apple [зело любят](https://www.defectivebydesign.org/apple) технические средства ограничения потребительских прав (DRM) и используют их даже когда не нужно; GNU (A)GPL же не допускает DRM. Несколько лет назад была история с удалением VLC из AppStore на этой почве — VideoLAN тогда пошли на уступки и ослабили лицензию.

Answer (score -2):

Раз либа - опенсорс, да еще и распространяется по свободной лицензии - вы ничего не нарушаете и можете свободно использовать её в своих целях. И, как правило, такие штучки не запрещают использовать и в коммерческих проектах.

Comment: IMHO (но запросто могу и ошибаться) не все так просто.

--

Суть в том,  что лицензии GNU направлены на то, чтобы предоставить *конечному пользователю* возможность доступа к *исходному коду*.

Т.е. если вы используете библиотеку под лицензией GNU, именно вы должны озаботится как оповещением конечного пользователя о том, что он эту библиотеку (пусть даже косвенно) использует, так и о пути доступа пользователя (на самом-то деле ему это нафиг не надо) к релевантным исходникам этой библиотеки. 

--

Где-то я читал, что прецеденты *"вычислить и покарать"* за нарушение GNU-лицензий в мире были.

Comment: @avp, ну, как правило, разработчики никак не карают за использование своих опенсурсных трудов (разве что самые жадные), ибо на кофе довольные кодеры накидают в любом случае. 
А если кому то сильно захочется - он найдет пути, лишь бы не платить

Comment: @Виталий RS, дело тут как раз не в жадности, а в неком принципе -- *информация должна быть свободна* 

(что-то вроде уважения к флагу и др. атрибутам в обыденной жизни).